# jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1 header button position left and right not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, position

When I jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js upgrade to jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1.min.js header design view is broken. Any idea on an easy way to accomplish this. I would appreciate your help.

```
<body style="background-color: #222">
<div data-role="page" data-position="fixed" id="pageDiv">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="inline">
        <a data-icon="back" class="headerButton" data-role="button" data-rel="back">Back</a>
        <h1>Mobil - @ViewBag.HeaderString</h1>
        <a data-icon="minus" id="logout" data-role="button" class="headerButton" href="@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")">Exit</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" style="min-height:inherit">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would not `alpha` releases potentially be buggy? ... try a newer version without `alpha`.

Comment: I could not provide the button view on the left and right sides of the header. I will be using JQueryMobile 1.5.0 as it is required to use JQuery 3.0 or higher. But not working